# Bind location of empty to vertex (after shapekeys)

Tags: constraints, shape-keys

For a rather complex technical animation.
I need an empty to be locked to a vertex.
I cannot simply make create parent-root scenario, or use bones for this.
As the vertex is modified by complex animated shapekeys.
So how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 5):

You can make a [Vertex Parent](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/properties/relations/parents.html#vertex-parent):

**Place an empty**. In Edit mode select your vertex, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > "cursor to selected". Back to object mode, add an Empty.

**Select the empty and the mesh in that order**. With the empty selected, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> on the mesh.

**Make vertex parent**. Back in edit mode, select the vertex, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> > "make vertex parent".

[image]
<sup>the gif shows the last two steps</sup>

Comment: Sadly cannt do, because the object parent is also used for linking other objects who should not be affected by it. though i got to say this is a nice trick to know so I +1.

Comment: That's fine! Also I haven't thought of your solution; glad you solved it

Answer (score 4):

Well I found a solution, took me a while.
Since other people might get into this as well, here is the solution:

On the object with shapekey select a vertex, create a vertex group for it.
On the Empty use a Child-Of constraint, select the object and the new vertex group.

Note its even possible this way to copy rotation of that vertex as well.

Answer (score 0):

In blender 2.83, you can go into edit mode, select the vertex you want, and search for (with f3) "hook to new object". This adds a empty in object mode, and when you move that empty it moves the vertex.
This method works with single or multiple vertices.[image: Here I have hooked the top 4 vertices individually, and hooked the bottom face. This image was taken in object mode.]Here I have hooked the top 4 vertices individually, and hooked the bottom face. This image was taken in object mode.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: The question is to move empty with vertex. Not to move vertex with empty.